# Twitter Bootstrap - Carousel Transition is NOT Smooth

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

StackOverflow,

I got the twitter carousel to work, but the transition to the next slide is very rough.

It moves in smoothly and at the last second, moves down and snaps into position.

[Here](http://screencast.com/t/zxei1pdrprIz) is a screen-cap for reference:

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What browser are you using (Safari/Firefox?)? It works perfectly for me on Chrome.

Comment: Can you post a test case on jsfiddle.net? That is a very weird issue.

Answer (score 7):

I found the carousel doesn't play nicely with padding. If you can't avoid using padding (as I couldn't), try to position the .next and .prev elements of the carousel using 'top', 'left', 'right' respective to which side you're adjusting so as to offset the shift.

You may have to tinker with it repeatedly through reloading to see how much more it needs to be adjusted.

For example, to offset a 40px padding in the carousel-inner element and other padding among the elements aligned left and right, I used:

```
.carousel .next {
  top: 40px;
  padding-left: 160px;
}

.carousel .prev {
  top: 40px;  
  padding-left: 160px;  
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the padding issue. It saved me some time in debugging that.