# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel is not smooth on Safari

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, safari, carousel, smoothing

I implemented Bootstrap Carousel as page transition for site http://singhabenelux.com/. But transition effect displays differently on Chrome and Safari. 
On safari, effect of changing to new page is not smooth, very slow and it seems old page and new page overlap.

Here is Css code for the carousel:
http://singhabenelux.com/wp-content/themes/dragonfroot/css/carousel.css

I think that -webkit-{attribute} will affect on chrome and safari also, but I don't know why there're difference between Chrome and Safari like this.

I'm testing on:
Chrome 38.0.2125.101
Safari 5.1.4
My OS is Windows8 Pro.

Please help me.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: I would first try optimizing your resources first. It seems that once everything is loaded it starts working correctly. Having 1.5MB images is going to be problematic in several regards.Optimize the page and then see how things work.

Comment: thank you so much, I solved the problem, it is smooth now. I optimized images and removed these code on css file: 
/*-webkit-transition: left 0.3s linear 0s;
          transition: left 0.3s linear 0s;*/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: Recap of what @Paul Kane wrote here: [Twitter Bootstrap - Carousel Transition is NOT Smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043098/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-transition-is-not-smooth)

I found the carousel doesn't play nicely with padding. If you can't avoid using padding (as I couldn't), try to position the .next and .prev elements of the carousel using 'top', 'left', 'right' respective to which side you're adjusting so as to offset the shift.

You may have to tinker with it repeatedly through reloading to see how much more it needs to be adjusted.

For example, to offset a 40px padding in the carousel-inner element and other padding among the elements aligned left and right, I used:

```
.carousel .next {
  top: 40px;
  padding-left: 160px;
}

.carousel .prev {
  top: 40px;  
  padding-left: 160px;  
}
```

This looks very promising as well: https://medium.com/@haydenbleasel/enhancing-bootstrap-carousel-performance-with-css3-29bfb20d1324

Answer (score 0):

It's important not to forget the `.slide` class for the `.catrousel` element:

```
<section class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
```